# How to react properly to component field changes?

Tags: unity, component-based

Let's say, that we have the following components:

`Direction`, which contains direction the object moves:

```
public class Direction : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float angle = 0.0f;

    public float Angle
    {
        get
        {
            return angle;
        }
        set
        {
            angle = value;
        }
    }
}
```

`DirectionVisualizer`, which visualizes this direction in form of a sphere:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Direction))]
public class DirectionVisualization : MonoBehaviour
{
    private const float Radius = 2.0f;
    private GameObject sphere;

    private void PositionSphere()
    {
        Direction direction = GetComponent<Direction>();
        float angle = direction.Angle;

        Vector3 position = transform.position + new Vector3(
            Radius * Mathf.Sin(angle * Mathf.PI / 180.0f),
            0.0f,
            Radius * Mathf.Cos(angle * Mathf.PI / 180.0f));
        sphere.transform.position = position;
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        sphere = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
        sphere.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

        PositionSphere();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

The relation above represents simplified model I'm having in my game - a component is used to visualize a set of parameters contained in other component(s).

Now I'd like the sphere to be automatically positioned basing on the `angle` field in `Direction` component without explicitly notifying `DirectionVisualization`, like:

```
var direction = someObj.GetComponent<Direction>();
direction.Angle = 25; // DirectionVisualization reacts automatically here
```

The simplest solution is to position sphere frame by frame, but I know, that `Angle` will change very infrequently and such solution would have dramatic impact on performance (in my game this visualization is a lot more complex).

I might do that by merging `Direction` and `DirectionVisualization` classes, such that I can handle `Angle` property setter, but that's a very ugly solution directly against SRR principle. So it's a no-go.

Other solution would be to create an event in `Direction` component and subscribe to it from within the `DirectionVisualization` component. But that raises following concerns:

- If `DirectionVisualization` is destroyed, the event handler will keep it alive (I should probably detach the event handler when `DirectionVisualization` is destroyed?)
- When `DirectionVisualization` is added to object, it should subscribe to `Direction`'s event
- What should happen if DirectionVisualization is added to object, which does not (yet) have Direction component? Is there a way to detect adding Direction component, such that DirectionVisualization might subscribe to the event?
- What happens if `Direction` component is destroyed? How DirectionVisualization should behave? Is there way to detect it?

Is there a better way to handle notifications between components than one I proposed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I personally would go with the event sending, because it's more explicit and easier to follow in code. Something like:

```
public delegate void DirectionChangedHandler(float direction);

public class Direction {
    [SerializeField]
    private float angle = 0.0f;

    public event DirectionChangedHandler DirectionChanged;

    public float Angle
    {
        get
        {
            return angle;
        }
        set
        {
            angle = value;
            DirectionChanged?.Invoke(value);
        }
    }
}

[RequireComponent(typeof(Direction))]
public class DirectionVisualization : MonoBehaviour
{
    Direction directionComponent;

    void OnEnable() {
        directionComponent = GetComponent<Direction>();
        directionComponent.DirectionChanged += OnDirectionChanged;
    }

    void OnDisable() {
        directionComponent.DirectionChanged -= OnDirectionChanged;
        directionComponent = null;
    }

    void OnDirectionChanged(float direction) {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

- [`OnDisable`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnDisable.html) will be called when component is removed. So nothing will keep it alive.
- [`OnEanable`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnEnable.html) will be called when component is added to game object.
- `RequireComponent` will make sure `Direction` component is added first.
- You can't remove `Direction` component if `DirectionVisualization` component is still present, because of `RequireComponent` attribute.

You can also send messages with [`GameObject.SendMessage()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SendMessage.html), this way you don't need to worry about event subscription.

Comment: One note, I'm not really sure if this is true: "You can't remove Direction component if DirectionVisualization component is still present, because of RequireComponent attribute." - do you have any source about this one?

Comment: Just try:
    `public class A: MonoBehaviour {
    }
    [RequireComponent(typeof(A))]
    public class B: MonoBehaviour {
        void Update() {
            Destroy(GetComponent<A>());
        }
    }`
And you get: "Can't remove A (Script) because B (Script) depends on it"